# Accessing the data set in a function of a globally define variable in another function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm still a bit of a noob at JS and thus I have the following question. I have this JS:

```
var twoFactorAuthCode;

fs.readFile('file.2fa', function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        logger.warn('Error reading neyotbot1.2fa. If this is the first run, this is expected behavior: '+err);
     } else {
        logger.debug("Found two factor authentication file. Attempting to parse data.");
        twoFactorAuth = JSON.parse(data);
        SteamTotp.getTimeOffset(function (error, offset, latency) {
          if (error) {
            logger.warn('Error retrieving the time offset from Steam servers: ' + error);
          } else {
            timeOffset = offset + latency;
          }
        });
        console.log(twoFactorAuthCode); //returns undefined
        twoFactorAuthCode = SteamTotp.getAuthCode(twoFactorAuth.shared_secret, timeOffset);
        console.log(twoFactorAuthCode); //returns what is expected
    }
    console.log(twoFactorAuthCode); //also returns what is expected
});

client.logOn({
  accountName:    config.username,
  password:       config.password,
  twoFactorCode:  twoFactorAuthCode //this is still set as undefined
});
```

My problem is that although the variable twoFactorAuthCode has a global scope, when it's assigned a value in the fs.readFile() function, it does not carry the data over to the next function client.logOn().

My question is, is it possible to get the data from the first function over to the second function using the variable. 
I couldn't find anything simple enough to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your arguments to `client.logOn` are *initialised* before your other function is called. Put that call inside another function and call it after the other one.

```
function myLogOn() {
  client.logOn({
    accountName:    config.username,
    password:       config.password,
    twoFactorCode:  twoFactorAuthCode
  });
};
myLogOn();
```

If `fs.readFile` is asynchronous, you may even need to move the call to `logOn` to be inside the callback function.